# Call iPyWidgets from own class doesn´t show

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipywidgets

I try to call a button from iPyWidgets over my own class but unfortunately it will not show the widget. But when I call the widget code directly in the console (Jupyterhub) it shows the button. This is my code

callButton.py

```
from here.analysis.testUI import TestUI
def call_button():
    test = TestUI()
    go = test.button()
    go
```

testUi.py

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Button, HBox, VBox, Layout, Button, Text, Textarea

class TestUI():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Just initialized")

    def button(self):
        #Maybe a return is not needed, but it also doesn´t work without a return
        return widgets.Button(description = 'clear', layout=Layout(width='20%', height='100%'))
```

And I am calling it in the Python console like so:

```
from here.analysis.callButton import call_button
call_button()
```

So why is the button not showing up? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button is explicitly displayed using `display(button)` in call_button.py